# are there other sites similiar to coinbase and circle.com

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

does anyone know of any other bitcoin wallet sites that offer the same instant usd to bitcoin exchange services, such as coinbase and circle.com? I must also be able to withdraw instantly to a linked bank account or credit card too. if anyone knows of a bitcoin site with same services as coinbase and circle.com for usa residents,please respond back. thank you